# Jquery click event not firing in a timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to trigger a click event when one button becomes visible.for some reasons this button takes about ~1 second to become visible in the page.so a made this function with timeout for detect when the button appears and trigger the click event.I've tried but for some reason the click event is not fired,the button's appearance detection is correct, only the click event don't work.These are the codes:

the 'cta' is the button id.

```
$(function checkBotaoApareceu(){
  console.log('teste');
  if($('#cta').is(':visible')){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#cta').click();
      console.log('click');
    }, 2000);
    return;
  }                        
  setTimeout( checkBotaoApareceu, 10 );
});
```

And here is my click event handler for the button

```
$('#cta').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#cta').hide();
    blocoAmarelo = $('div .bloco-amarelo');
    $("#the_lights").css('height',$(document).height());
    $("#the_lights").css('display','block');
    $("#the_lights").fadeTo(1000,0.8);
    blocoAmarelo.show();
    blocoAmarelo.click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$('html').click(function() {
    if(document.getElementById("the_lights").style.display === 'block'){
        document.getElementById("the_lights").style.display="none";
    }
});
```

note: the stopPropagation calls are needed here to keep some div style.

Comment: Is your click handler inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/56dqpLv4/

Answer (score 0):

I Still dont know what was causing the error.but after some research this solution worked for me.

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
    if (el.fireEvent) {
      el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
    } else {
      var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
      evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
      el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
    }
}

$(function(){
    var id = setInterval(function (){
        if ($('#cta').is(':visible')) {
            eventFire(document.getElementById('cta'),'click');                
            clearInterval(id);
        }
    }, 100);
});
```